# I get the configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found by running in a docker container on ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When I look to my publish files and on the server the files appsettings.json are there and they are configure in the publish.

When I do a Console.WriteLine of env.ContentRootPath in startup, the contentRootPath is /.

It should be the path to the folder where the application has been installed?

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(" ContentRootPath: " + env.ContentRootPath);

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `appsettings.json` file is included in your docker build?

Comment: Not sure how to check in a container to see if a file is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is related to my docker file and where I copy the program.

I was copying the directory of the program in root in the container and I suspect that my user that run kestrel doesn't had access to that root folder and can't see the files.

FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
   **COPY /app /root/**
   EXPOSE 5001/tcp
   ENTRYPOINT dotnet **/root/App.dll**

I use than another script for docker file that simply copy the folder and my AppSettings file where found and loaded correctly.

FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
   **WORKDIR /app**
   ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5001
   EXPOSE 5001
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App.dll"]
   **COPY . /app**

[Github with a similar issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5193)